# Bokeh Area Chart unable to plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I am unable to plot the area chart in bokeh for some reason..

Below is the code used for the same..

```
from bokeh.charts import Area, show, output_file 

Areadict = dict( 
    I = df['IEXT'], 
    Date=df['Month'], 
    O = df['OT'] 
) 

 area = Area(Areadict, x='Date', y=['I','O'], title="Area Chart", 
             legend="top_left", 
               xlabel='time', ylabel='memory') 

 output_file('area.html') 
 show(area)
```

All i see if the date axis getting plotted, but no signs of the two areacharts that I am interested in.
Please advise

Comment: What are your data ? what does df["Month"] or df['IEXT'] look like ?

Comment: @Louc : df['Iext'] is float type. Values in millions/billions.. Same goes for df['OT']...
Do these all numbers need to be positive ? Is that the reason ?
df['Month'] is simply the yyyy-mm format datetime...

Comment: I already run into blank bokeh plot because my data was not well formated : for example with incorrect decimal type (, or . in the orignal file, imported as object and not float by pandas), or with incorrect DateTime. I often need to explicitly tell pandas that my data are DateTime, for example : df = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ";", header = 8, index_col = 0, decimal = ",") and 
df.index = pd.to_datetime(arg = df.index, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") I need to dig a little for Area() because I never used this function in Bokeh

Comment: The format of the data should not be a problem for my end, as I have been working on this same dataframe and have been performing similar vizualizations and other pandas/numpy operations as well..
Will be interesting to see if it is really the data format or ordering that plays a role here..

Comment: hmm, bokeh.charts isn't present in current version (0.12.14), it's obsolete. I'm loolinkg for replacement or old bokeh version

Comment: @Louc I am little confused now with your reply.... I am using 0.12.5 and have been using bokeh.charts for Bar, Scatter, etc..

Comment: The current version is [0.12.14](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2018/2/7/release-0-12-14/), bokeh.charts api is obsolete since [version 0.12.9 (september 2017)](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/releases/0.12.9.html). I personnaly never used it, I only plot timeseries curves, that's why I need looking a bit further to reproduce your problem

Comment: Thanks @Louc. It will be really good if a solution can be reached. Coz I also struggled with Horizon chart that I tried a few days back.
Is there Bokeh Support ? Unfortunately bokeh guys seems to be on googlegroups which is not accessible from workplaces...

Comment: you can try to reach them from [github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at [Holoviews](http://holoviews.org) which is a very high level API built on top of Bokeh, and is endorsed by the Bokeh team. You can see an Area chart example [in their documentation](http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/area_chart.html#bokeh-gallery-area-chart). Basically it looks like:

```
# create holoviews objects
dims = dict(kdims='time', vdims='memory')
python = hv.Area(python_array, label='python', **dims)
pypy   = hv.Area(pypy_array,   label='pypy',   **dims)
jython = hv.Area(jython_array, label='jython', **dims)

# plot
overlay.relabel("Area Chart") + hv.Area.stack(overlay).relabel("Stacked Area Chart")
```

Which results in

[image]

Otherwise, as of Bokeh 0.13 to create a stacked area chart with the stable `bokeh.plotting` API, you will need to stack the data yourself, as shown in [this example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/brewer.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.palettes import brewer

N = 20
cats = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 100, size=(N, cats))).add_prefix('y')

def  stacked(df):
    df_top = df.cumsum(axis=1)
    df_bottom = df_top.shift(axis=1).fillna({'y0': 0})[::-1]
    df_stack = pd.concat([df_bottom, df_top], ignore_index=True)
    return df_stack

areas = stacked(df)
colors = brewer['Spectral'][areas.shape[1]]
x2 = np.hstack((df.index[::-1], df.index))

p = figure(x_range=(0, N-1), y_range=(0, 800))
p.grid.minor_grid_line_color = '#eeeeee'

p.patches([x2] * areas.shape[1], [areas[c].values for c in areas],
          color=colors, alpha=0.8, line_color=None)

show(p)
```

which results in

[image]