# Bokeh - Format Label With Percent Sign

Tags: python, bokeh

Using Python3 and Bokeh 0.13.0

I have a plot which is using float numbers like 22.6. These numbers are actually percents. I have labels for each point on a line but I can't figure out a way to include a % sign in the label (like 22.6%). I was able to format the axis fine, but the labels are giving me a hard time. Here is the portion of the code that defines the label.

```
labels = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='y', level='glyph',y_range_name="line",
                      x_offset=-8, y_offset=10, source=source_line, render_mode='canvas',
                      text_font_size='8pt', text_color='white', background_fill_color="gray")
p.add_layout(labels)
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

- You can pre-format all the data in python, store it in a new column in your `ColumnDataSource`, and use that to drive the label text, i.e. something like

  ```
  source.data['formatted_y'] = ["%f %" % x for x in source.data['y']]
  LabelSet(text='formatted_y', ...)
  ```
- You can use a `CustomJSTransform` to transform the data on the JavaScript end, e.g.

  ```
  from bokeh.models import CustomJSTransform
  from bokeh.transform import transform

  formatter = CustomJSTransform('y',  func="", v_func="""
      out = []
      for (i=0; i < xs.length; i ++) {
         out.push(xs[i] + " %")
      }
      return out
  """)
  LabelSet(text=transform('y', formatter), ...)
  ```

  *Note: untested, since you did not provide a complete example code it could be tested with, but should be in the ballpark*

Comment: unrelated `Area` question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881348/bokeh-area-chart-unable-to-plot/52009217#52009217

Comment: Thanks  I ended up using holoviews which made the area plotting pretty simple. edit...and apparently that answer suggested that library too.